# Android Fragments: how do I save and pass data back to parent activity once the user closes the current activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have a `SearchFragment` and a `PersonFragment` which are hosted by different `FragmentActivity`s

The user will navigate from the `SearchFragment` to the `PersonFragment`. When the user is done with the `PersonFragment` (such as when they press the back button), I would like to send data back to `SearchFragment` so it can update its UI with any changes the user made while in `PersonFragment`.

I read the best way to do this is in the Activity's `finish()` method. However, since I'm using fragments I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: You have to implement an interface , communicate with the activity rather than the fragment. Here is a complete guide:http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: The question is why are you using two activitys for your fragments when they depend on eachother? Host them both in the same activity and implement a listener interface

Comment: you can go through https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus all though i haven't tried it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) for this

Answer (score 0):

You first communicate from `PersonFragment` to the associated activity using interface as a callback.

Then you can use intent to pass values between activities. From activity you can communicate to `SearchFragment`.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the tutorial on the Android developers site ([link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)), you should declare a listener interface in your PersonFragment, implement it in your FragmentActivity and in that implementation, update your SearchFragment's UI.

Edit: Another approach would be to use LocalBroadcastManager, if you can package your relevant data in an Intent, this approach uses a bit less boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need it, all you need to do is some ContentObserver that notifies you about the content changes, see ContentResolver and its methods:  registerContentObserver() and notifyChange()